# Is it good idea to inline CSS that is not used elsewhere across the site?

Tags: html, css, optimization, page-load-time

I don't know if this question asked before, if yes then please comment the link for that post

So we have a pretty big website with almost 1000 - 1200 pages and around 90% of those page have unique classes for hero banner and icons. So i want to know if inlining only `background-image` property for hero banner and `background-postion, width, height` property icons is good idea or not, as doing this will hugely reduce the size of our CSS file. Currently we have CSS size of about 500kb and if we do this file size will came down to 200kb leaving only the theme styles in my stylesheet. In addition to this how it will impact page performance/ and First content full Paint.
My Base class for herobanner

```
.herobanner{
  min-height: 450px;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(../img/dummy.jpg);
  background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

How i call banner

```
.somebanner{
   background-image: url(../img/background/somebanner);
}
```

For Icons

```
.sprite {
  background-image: url(../img/sprite/Teal_Icons.png);
  display: inline-block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
 .icon-1{
   background-position: -420px -214px;
   width: 70px;
   height: 69px;
 }
```

Comment: Why not split it in to two classes: a base class with ```background-postion, width, height``` and a specific class with ```background-image```?

Comment: instead of inline css you might want to use <img>

Comment: using background images for your main hero seems a bit wrong - it gives it no visibility and is bad for seo as well as not allowing users to print it with the page, unless they manually turn on background image printing

Comment: @OlegG We already have a base class for icons which calls a sprite sheet and few common properties for all icons and same goes hero shot, after which we use a separate class to call hero banner and icons using the properties of base class

Comment: @IbnRushd can use <img> as there is some text content come over it

Comment: @pete Our site not intend for the user who prints the page and as far as seo is considered we are not hiding anything from the search engine so i think we are fine there

Comment: And accessibility? if it's a main banner, should it not have the proper prominence and alternative text?

Comment: @Pete You are right but we are more focused towards optimization, as most of the classes in stylesheet are not used elsewhere, thats why i am thinking of doing these

Comment: Again if you use an image instead of background image, it will cut down on all the classes you need for the image width and height and background-image - which seems to be what you want to do?  If you are sure that the classes are not used in other things then I would probably move them into the head of the files - easier to maintain than in-lining them

Comment: @pete I have update the sample css i have used in my project, please have look at it. Currently most space is accquired by unique classes like `someabnner` and `icon-1` and want to inline these only. Yeah i know <img> would be better option but using this will be a good option for us right now as image have some text content over it and have to restructuring an for that block or all the page which will take a lot of time as we have to test them and doing this way we will be sure it will not impact the design

Comment: You see here I would leave base class in main and then inline the image, as for the sprite - if it is only used in one place, does it need to be a sprite... (same concept as your large stylesheet really - do you need to load the whole thing if you only use part of it) - this may be a better question on codereview stack exchnage as you have css that works and you are wanting to know how to make it netter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174819/discussion-between-akash-and-pete).

Comment: @pete I got your point regarding the sprite as few a icons are only need per page and it increase the load time, but we have lot of icons is sprite which is impossible task for us to separate now, for better optimization in think it will be better inline style for those icons and to use individual icons for page in future

Answer (score 0):

The CSS landscape has changed drastically over the pat 5 years. There are a lot of great tools out there for implementing styles in your project - you just need to find the one that fits your workflow. More on that in a moment.

As for your question specifically, its my opinion that inline styles should be used very sparingly. Placing a style inline holds greater specificity than most other options making edits much more tedious. The gains you would see in file size would be overshadowed by the increased time to make edits to CSS across 1000-1200 pages.

I don't know what your project looks like, but maybe look into a compiler like SCSS, take a look at JSS, or something like CSS Modules may work for you.

Comment: Please have look at sample code i have updated. We have unique classed like `somebanner` and `icon-1` for almost all the pages. So i just want to inline those classes as they are not used any where and same goes with icon and remove them from stylesheet

Comment: Does each icon require that level of specificity? Without knowing all of the details, it sounds like the issue may lie with the framework of the site if every hero image and icon has to be placed so specifically.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not saying your framework is bad, I'm just saying the issue you are dealing with could be a result of the framework.

My suggestion would be to use <img>, similar to what others have suggested.

Comment: No it dosen't require the specificity, and yes it is problem of framework you can say on how everyone previously has worked on it, right now i just want to optimize every thing in little time and place improvements for the future. As image thing will be requiring testing of every page and redoing that block of code on every page

Comment: Yeah, that's tough. Sorry I don't have anything valuable to offer. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

ok in that case i have created this function for my own projects.

any element with for example **"hasbg"** class will get the background image from **data-img** attribute.

and if you put **data-fixed** attribute equal to **"fixed"** it will be a parallax image.

you can change the options to pass parameters for background position if you want.

also i have added an if block to check if its a mobile device disable fixed element to stop bugs.

i hope it helps

```js
function bgSize() {
  var bg = $('.hasbg'),
    fx = '';
  bg.each(function(index, el) {
    fx = $(el).attr('data-fixed') ? $(el).attr('data-fixed') : '';
    $(el).css('background', 'url(' + $(el).data('img') + ') 50% 50% / cover ' + fx);
  });
  if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    bg.css({
      'background-attachment': 'scroll'
    });
  }
}

bgSize();
```

```css
.hasbg {
  min-height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="hasbg" data-img="http://via.placeholder.com/120x120"></div>
<div class="hasbg" data-img="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"></div>
<div class="hasbg" data-img="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks i am already aware of this solution but in this case how this is different in respect to manually writing style to the element as jQuery is also doing the same.  Will this method have better page performance in comparison with inlining the css?

Comment: no difference on performance but a lot easier for you. and more important clean html

Answer (score -2):

There is no "Best practice" for CSS just various approaches. The most common is to use style sheets due to the benefit of code reuse and maintainability, you only need to go to one place to edit the styling and it helps with separating concerns.

However if you are creating "unique" styles for each page this benefit will have largely been lost.

Partially related to this is specificity,

Every selector has its place in the specificity hierarchy. There are four categories which define the specificity level of a selector:

- Inline styles - An inline style is attached directly to the element to be styled.
- IDs - An ID is a unique identifier for the page elements.
- Classes, attributes and pseudo-classes
- Elements and pseudo-elements.

[image]

The aim of the game here is always use the least specific selector possible, this gives the maximum room to override later if needed. This is a large topic on its own so i will provide a link to more information. The main thing to take away here is that using inline styles is not advised.

- [Further Information](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

In your case it sounds as though you have a set of common properties that are repeated, To reduce the code firstly I would separate out these common properties as below

Create a common class

```
.banner{
  min-height: 450px;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }

.dummy{
  background-image: url(../img/dummy.jpg);
  background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.foo{
  background-image: url(../img/foo.jpg);
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

These can then be applied using:

```
class:"banner foo"
```

This can then be cut down further by using the background shorthand property.

```
.dummy {
    background: #fff url(../img/dummy.jpg); no-repeat center top;
}
```

When using the shorthand property the order of the property values is:

- background-color
- background-image
- background-repeat
- background-attachment
- background-position

It does not matter if one of the property values is missing, as long as the other ones are in this order.

Comment: Sorry brother i think you didn't get my actual question, i am well aware of specificity but here it is not the problem. It more related to optimize our stylesheet by removing unique class we have created in our style-sheet for every page and inlining them to there respective page and if it is good approach or not.

Comment: It's considered good to keep your css and your html separate. By adding in-line styles it becomes more difficult to change the look of a site, it makes it more difficult for future programmers to modify your site. If everything is in a CSS file, then you can change the entire design of your site without having to mess with the data (HTML) of the site. So my advice do not use inline styles.

I would apply the following to your css 

Minify the CSS file, Reduce unnecessary code (my original comment)
Splitting CSS files - separate IE/Chrome specific code.